# SSH login: automatically goto last directory visited?

Tags: linux, ssh, login

During my multitasking days, sometimes I will be booted off of an SSH session for one reason or another (idle timeouts, etc), while I am working on another task. When I return to the terminal, I will find myself back at localhost, needing to SSH back to the server. Once back at the server, I'm always in my `~` home directory by default and I need to navigate back to the directory I was at last (if I can remember it) in order to continue working.

Is it possible to automatically return to the last directory I was working in when I login?

I was thinking a homebrew solution would be aliasing `cd` to change directories but also save that directory into some environment variable, and then changing to that directory in my `.bash_profile`.

But is there any sort of functionality like this already in Linux?

Answer (score 7):

Instead of solving the `cd` persistence problem, you should consider solutions to resume your shell session.

- [`tmux`](http://tmux.sourceforge.net)

  - Inside SSH, run `tmux` to start a new session
  - If disconnected, SSH in again, and run `tmux attach` to resume the session
  - Inside a `tmux` session, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>, then <kbd>D</kbd> to detach
- [`screen`](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/)

  - Inside SSH, run `screen` to start a new session
  - If disconnected, SSH in again, and run `screen -r` to resume the session
  - Inside a `screen` session, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>, then <kbd>D</kbd> to detach
- [`mosh`](http://mosh.mit.edu)

  - `mosh` is an SSH replacement that runs over UDP and is designed to be resistant to network disruptions

Comment: +1 for adding "mosh". Looks very interesting. "byobu" could be added on top of screen.

Comment: `screen` is interesting. I noticed that if I run a long process in a remote SSH window, then close the session, reopen it and go `screen -r`, it goes right back to where I left off, as if the process was still running. Is this sort of like a `NOHUP` thing? I can execute a long process and then don't worry about leaving the terminal open?

Comment: @jakobud exactly.  Things inside screen keep running after you disconnect.

Answer (score 2):

No need for any 3rd party software or app, just use built-in linux

1. when log out, assign $PWD (last dir) to a temporary var before logout:

echo $PWD >~/lastdir

2. when log in, cd that dir at ~/.bash_profile:

cd $(<~/lastdir)

Answer (score 2):

1. Can append below statement to  ~/.bash_logout

   ```
   echo `pwd` >~/.lastdir
   ```
2. (as @isaac-Zhao suggested) add the following to ~/.bash_profile

   ```
   cd $(<~/.lastdir)
   ```